# Angular JS App and JSPDF not working in IE at all

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jspdf

I have an application in Angular JS and it is using JSPDF.

The problem is that generating the PDF works in Chrome, Firefox and Safari but not in IE at all. There, I get the following error:

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'trimLeft' 
jspdf.plugin.from_html.js, line 71 character 4
```

Code in js file for generating the PDF:

```
 function mainControl($scope) {

    $scope.showtooltip = false;
    $scope.value = 'Generate PDF';

    $scope.hideTooltip = function() {
      $scope.showtooltip = false;
    }

    $scope.toggleTooltip = function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      $scope.value = 'HERE';
      $scope.showtooltip = !$scope.showtooltip;
    }
  }

  function printPDF() {

    var doc = new jsPDF();
    var elementHandler = {
      '#oi' : function(element, renderer) {
        return true;
      }
    };

    var source = window.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

    doc.fromHTML($('#content').get(0), 10, 15, {
      'width' : 190
    });


    doc.setFont("helvetica");
    doc.setFontType("normal");
    doc.setTextColor(198, 0, 24);
    doc.setFontSize(10);
    doc.text(10, 10,  'xxxx');

    doc.output("dataurlnewwindow")  
  }

  var Show = {
    getFromPDF : function() {
      $('#btn-pdf').click(function() {
        printPDF();
      });
    }
  }

  $(function() {
    Show.getFromPDF();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

IE does not support the non-standard function `trimLeft` of String.prototype, for more info check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/TrimLeft#Browser_compatibility)

Here is a workaround :

```
<!--[IF IE]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (typeof String.prototype.trimLeft !== 'function') {
        String.prototype.trimLeft = function() {
            return this.replace(/^\s*/,'');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here is a working demo:

```js
if (typeof String.prototype.trimLeft !== 'function') {
  String.prototype.trimLeft = function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s*/, '');
  }
}


var myString = "                                         YEBO zsdsad sadsad    ";
console.log("test");
console.log(myString.trimLeft());
```

Comment: @Sole you can put it in a js file and then include it before your JSPDF